# Internal and external parallelism

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, parallel-processing, cilk

What is difference between internal and external parallelism? If one solution(visual studio) has 2 projects then how can we define parallelism by internal or external?

Thanks

Comment: Why is the "cilk" tag on this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Internal parallelism** is when tasks are performed in parallel within the system being analyzed and not known from its outside world (black box).

**External parallelism** is when tasks are performed in parallel between the system and its  outside world.

Generally, these terms are more used in a hardware system context.

In the context of C++ software example that you give, I'd say internal parallelism is about [mutlithreading](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/multithreading/) (internal to one process/project) whereas external parallelism is about parallelism between the two [processes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684841%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)/projects of your solution (and may require [interprocess communication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).